# SSL BIO and FFI

Tags: c, haskell, ssl, openssl

I have a streaming API in Haskell (not unlike OpenSSL's BIOs) that I'd like to inject an SSL/TLS "proxy" into. To be more specific, let's say I have a model of a network

`Server| <---> |Logger>| <---> |<Logger| <---> |Client`

(where I'm writing `Logger>` to mean a "downstream" logger) and I'd like to write an FFI to call into OpenSSL to inject TLS into the center here

`Server| <---> |Logger>| <---> |TLS>| <---> |<TLS| <---> |<Logger| <---> |Client`

so that communication between `TLS>` and `<TLS` is encrypted. What is the simplest interface with OpenSSL that'll let me build `<TLS`? After that, what is the simplest interface to build `TLS>`?

Put another way, my project is different from most tutorials I've read because I want to be able to both `BIO_gets` and `BIO_puts` an SSL structure. This is similar to if I was managing my own transport for the SSL client connection, but the "transport" is carried out by lifting the C pointers up into Haskell.

(I'm sure that I'm simply totally missing something fundamental about the `SSL`+`BIO` interaction.)

---

From http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_bio.html I see an application like what I'm shooting for:

`BIO *internal_bio, *network_bio;`
`...`
`BIO_new_bio_pair(internal_bio, 0, network_bio, 0);`
`SSL_set_bio(ssl, internal_bio, internal_bio);`
`SSL_operations();`

which seems roughly correct. I'd be able to both `puts` and `gets` on `network_bio`.

Answer (score 1):

If openssl is not something required for your project and you could use any TLS library,
you could use the much simpler [tls](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls), which is better integrated with Haskell and has built-in support for custom transport through the [Backend](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tls/1.0.3/doc/html/Network-TLS.html#t%3aBackend) type. This will be much simpler than dealing with openssl lowlevel APIs through Haskell.

Comment: Although this is a bit of an advertisement for a library, it's very true. It's a hassle to get OpenSSL working on non-*NIX platforms, while the pure Haskell tls-package works wherever Haskell works. Incidentally, it's also easier to extend. OpenSSL is a damned monolithic mess, while tls delegates many tasks (encryption, hashing, marshalling) to other packages.

Comment: Yes, I originally suggested it for this reason; I had to deal with openssl in OCaml lots of moon ago, and it wasn't a pleasant experience. tls is not necessarily very well known, and lots of people are trying to deal with openssl because that's the only thing they know; However i just realized now that the same person opened a bug on the tls bug tracker couple of hours before his post here, so he probably know about tls, and as such my proposition is slightly inappropriate and i'm not helping with his problem. sorry !

Comment: Oh, hi! I tried `tls` first, but TLS is a pure computation in context of communication streams, some fixed certificate/key state, and a random gen so I'd prefer not to tie to the IO monad and have to worry about exceptions. I tried to lift the IO restriction a bit on a fork of `tls`, but it seems like a more complex project than just lifting the pure C computations. Finally, I don't care much about cross platform compatibility and will have an easier time defending an ancient, highly-vetted security library. For these reasons, `tls` isn't a good fit.